# SteamVR External Camera, Screen Position out of view frustum

Tags: unity-game-engine, steam, virtual-reality, htc-vive, openvr

I am currently working on SteamVR External Camera for the third controller, supporting Mixed Reality in my project for HTC Vive.

But I have a trouble with the Quadratic view, it shows only the HMD:
[image]

When I select the camera in the child of third controller, It gives this error : [image]

My hunch for this problem is because the Graphics.drawTexture() in the script, but I don't know the solution for it. I have searched this problem at Unity Forum but no answer there...

Any help will be appreciated.

Notes :

1. Unity v5.6.1f1
2. SteamVR v1.2.1